# Xcode OSX SDK is more current than my OS

Tags: xcode, macos

I am running OSX 10.10.5.

When I create a new Xcode command line project for OSX, the Base SDK is for 10.11. This doesn't seem to matter, as I can still run and archive and use the command line tool.

Today I used CMake to generate an Xcode project from a third-party library. When I open it, it also shows a Base SDK for 10.11. However, unlike my little command-line tool, when I run it, I get the message:

[image]

However, there are no other SDKs shown when I inspect the Xcode.app SDK directory, nor are there other options in the Base SDK field in Xcode.

My 2-part question:

1) Why does my own command-line tool not do this, but this third-party Xcode project does, when both have the same SDK listed?

2) How can I get a 10.10.5 SDK into my Xcode, or can't I?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The relevant setting is not the SDK, which governs the *maximum* level of features your app can use. It's the deployment target, which governs the *minimum* OS supported by your app.

Your App_HelloWorld target is apparently configured with a deployment target of 10.11. Change that to 10.10 or, perhaps, earlier. However, you have to be careful to either avoid any APIs that require a later version of the OS or do run-time checks before using any APIs newer than your deployment target to make sure they are available.

You can set the deployment target in the target General settings or the project Info settings.